# How can I group a pivot table showing missing quarters/years

Tags: excel, pivot

My source data sheet (in Excel) is missing some quarters and years. How can I make them show up with a value of 0 in my pivot table? (without touching my source table)
The normal group function just skips these entries, therefore, creating a chart does not make much sense...

Answer (score 1):

You just need to add the source data, one entry per missing quarters (with 0 value). It would be obviously cleaner to add EVERY quarter you need. If you don't want to add them to the original data, you add them in a separate spreadsheet and do the pivot table on both table (I think it's called multiple data consolidation).

Comment: Thanks, but that's exactly what I don't want to do. However, I think I've got my answer: it seems that I have to use a BI-tool for that.